# Number guessing game with illogical bug

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;
srand(time(NULL)); 

int main(){
    int botguess;
    int playerinput;
    int mi=1, ma=100;
    int turns = 0;
    cout<<" what do you want guessed:";

    cin>> playerinput;
    cout<< "time for me to start guessing\n";

    for(int i = 0;i < 50;i++) {
        botguess = rand() % ma + mi;

        if(playerinput > botguess){  //<--the problem 
            mi = botguess;
        }

        if(playerinput < botguess) {
            ma = botguess;
        }

        cout<<"Max:"<<ma<<"\n"<<botguess<<"\n";
        Sleep(1000);
        if(botguess == playerinput)
        {
            cout<<"you win";
        }
    }

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

So I've been tearing my hair out about why logically this doesn't work.  This is a program that is supposed to guess the players number quickly but not instantly.  The program doesn't perform like it looks.

The line that I noted causes a bug where the max number possible is being ignored. im getting number that are 100+ but under 200 and i don't know why.  When I remove the lines concerning the `mi` variable nested in the statement in the for loop.  The program doesn't go over 100 but I don't get the other end of the program solving the player number.

Also if you figure it out can you please explain it to me I don't just want a answer.

Comment: Don't forget to seed the random number generator at the start of your program, so that you don't get the same results every time: `srand(time(0));` will be fine for your purposes.

Comment: oh im sorry i already added that in my new write up.

Comment: Uhhh, by "the start of your program" I mean somewhere in `main()` before the loop.  You can't have it sitting there outside of any function body.  That's not the issue, it's just something that may help you.  Amadan has already provided an answer with a good explanation of your error and how to do the calculation as you intended it.

Answer (score 2):

```
botguess = rand() % (ma - mi + 1) + mi
```

You don't want `ma` different numbers, you want much less of them. Look at an example: `(5..10)` contains `6` different numbers: `[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`; but if you do `rand() % 10 + 5`, you're getting numbers from `5` (`5 + 0`) to `14` (`5 + 9`). What you need is `rand() % 6 + 5`, where `6` is `10 - 5 + 1`.

Comment: Thank you sooo much sitting here and logically thinking saved my love for programming in c++

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is caused by the fact that mi is set to botguess, which can easily be greater than zero, then on the next cycle if ma is still 100 (or anywhere near it), you're going to sometimes get numbers greater than 100 set into botguess.

Edit added: the % operator in C++ is mod division (ie. gives the remainder of integer division) So for example, 98 % 100 + 15 will be 98 + 15, i.e. 113

This link may help you:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/

Comment: Yeah, but they don't understand why.  That's the whole point of the question, which you failed to address.

Comment: In half the time it took you to criticize my post you could have explained what % did. I have to assume a certain level of knowledge from the poster. Otherwise we'll be here answering nested why's all the way down to, "ok so have you turned on your computer"

Comment: I was surprised at your defensive posture on my comment, as well as your idea that everybody needs things boiled down to first principles.  So, I wrote that comment in less than 10 seconds.  Are you suggesting that I could have written, in about 5 seconds, a suitable explanation of how the user has misunderstood how the modulo operator works, and how to correct their logic?  I am flattered =)

Comment: No, thank you for giving me the opportunity to clarify. I'm saying that I simply disagree with your comment that my first paragraph failed to address why. Perhaps you could help me understand what part of the Why (apart from a deeper explanation of module arithmetic) I had failed to address in my original answer? I'm really at a loss to see how my answer could have gone deeper into the Why without writing something that over simplifies for the majority of readers.

Comment: Okay fair enough.  To quote the question: *im getting number that are 100+ but under 200 and i don't know why. When I remove the lines concerning the mi variable nested in the statement in the for loop. The program doesn't go over 100 but I don't get the other end of the program solving the player number.* -- Your answer (prior to being edited) simply paraphrased their observations without offering any new insight that could help them understand.  I thought it was obvious that they needed help to understand and fix the modulo line.  I did not mean to offend you.

Comment: It's cool. Thank you for the clarification. I agree the % explanation helps.